# Using limit of a function to prove another limit

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to have a hint for the following problem about limit:

Prove $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = l \Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}f(1/x) = l$$
Now I know intuitively that the limit of $1/x$ as $x$ approaches infinity is $0$, but how can I approach this using the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of limits?

My try:

I know that $$\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0, 0<|x|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-l| < \epsilon$$ and I am trying to prove $$\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists N, x > N\Longrightarrow|f(1/x)-l| < \epsilon$$
I don't know what to do next since I am new to real analysis. Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to MSE so I don't know this. Is this edit good enough or do I have to show more? I am new to real analysis so I really have no idea what to do next. Can you please help?

Comment: Here's maybe a helpful hint: if $|x| <\delta$, then $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| > \frac{1}{\delta}$. So when there exists $N$ such that $\delta \leq \frac{1}{N}$, then $\frac{1}{\delta} \geq N$.

Comment: Now it's just fine.